# CSS navigation list item 100% height

Tags: css, navbar, listitem

Can somebody tell me please which css style is responsible for li element height of the green navbar on this page: http://natura.elias-itsolutions.sk/ All list items have 100% of the parent ul element but I dont understand how is it possible. There is no css for li height nor the inside a element has the style for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">` - container of those items and it's `display: flex`. The default for `align-items` property of a flex container is `stretch`. This is what makes the list items full height (stretched).

Comment: Yes I am still in the past before flex-box ... Thank you.

Comment: No problem man ! it's not very obvious if you don't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ul. Navbar-nav` added `display: flex`, `flex` default style `alt-items: stretch` Causes the child element to be the same height as the parent element.

Comment: Yes I am still in the past before flex-box ... Thank you